# Ruby Array [] method

Tags: ruby

`[]` used after an array is a method. It is defined like this:

```
def [] x
  //do something
end
```

So I think it should be used like:

```
array.[] x
```

Why can it then be used like the following?

```
array[x]
```

Comment: IMHO it's more of a convention. Ruby's inventor decides to make its grammar like this.

Comment: `[]` is not just for arrays, there's [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), [`Integer#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) and many more.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What answer, specifically, are you looking for other than "because the Ruby Language Specification say so"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called syntactic sugar, which helps you in lesser/ more readable code

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

a.[](1) #=> 2
```

More about this 
http://datamelon.io/blog/2015/square-brackets-in-ruby.html

Comment: Okay .. but why? I have tested this

Comment: Sorry I overlooked

Comment: A small point: it's better to write `#=>` than `=>` when showing return values. Among other things it it allows readers to run cut-and-pasted code without modification.

Comment: Aye sir! with all respect to copy paste developers ;)

Comment: thank you, i understand the the `a.[](1)`,  but i still don't know how it could be transformed to `a[1]`  ? maybe i  am too inquisitive.........

Comment: i have read the blog , i know that  `a[1]` is equal to  `a.[](1)` , i just want  to  know  when you write `a[1]`  , how  ruby know to invoke `a.[](1)`  :)

Comment: @Dearest just like Ruby knows that `i + 1` is `i.+(1)` or `i.send(:+, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If I add a pair of parentheses, then you may understand it clearly.

```
def [](x)
  // do something
end
```

It's the same syntax as defining a method. Its name is `[]` (a little bit weird), and it takes one argument `x`. And in fact, you are defining such method.

Comment: Read this answer first and my answer later for example :)

Comment: Same here ;) you have given the declaration part, and I have given the example part :D. I am liking this ...